# Android Java: Scaling down bitmap while keeping quality?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, scaling

I have a very high quality PNG, I'd like to scale it down without losing quality.

After importing my image to drawable-mdpi, here's what I've done:

```
titlelogo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.titlelogo);

titlelogoR = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(titlelogo,(int)width, (int)(titlelogo.getHeight()*(width/titlelogo.getWidth())), true);

canvas.drawBitmap((Bitmap)titlelogoR,0,0,null);
```

here's my original image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB8eK.png

and here's what it looks like on my device:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tldMo.png

thanks in advance!

edit: Q:why do I want to scale the image afterwards rather than beforehand? A:So the image can be the same size on all android devices; is there a better way of achieving this?

SOLVED!

I started my project right from the beginning and put my images in xxhdpi folder

Comment: If you never need that high of a quality image in your app, you might aswell scale it beforehand. If want to be prepared for multiple screen resolutions; work with the highest resolution as your base image and scale down from there, or use the appropriate ldpi/mdpi/hdpi folders.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way is to scale your image beforehand and put it into the mdpi folder. If you REALLY have to scale it in your app, put it in the raw folder.

Comment: Can I ask why you suggested putting it in the raw folder? Thanks

Comment: @JadeByfield: Well if you're not going to let the framework scale the image I would think the raw folder might be appropriate. It's actually been a while since I've manipulated images by hand on android so this might not be the best way. But fighting against the auto scaler can be really annoying.